# c using stdin in while(1) loop will loop multiple times if stdin is over buffer size

Tags: c

I am building a larger application than the code block I will show. But I will basically be asking for user input (like a turn) performing a task then asking for more user input. The issue I have ran into is best shown through my code sample.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    while(1){
        char *string = malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
        printf("enter string: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            char input = getchar();
            if(input == '\n'){
                break;
            }
            string[i] = input;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            printf("%d ", string[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

When I enter a string 0 - 5 characters the result is exactly as expected e.g.
`0 0 0 0 0 0 enter string:`  With no data or `97 98 99 0 0 0 enter string:`  when "abc" is entered.

However when more than 5 characters is entered the results are not as expected e.g.
`97 98 99 100 101 102 enter string: 103 0 0 0 0 0 enter string:`  When "abcdefg" is entered. For some reason it appears to loop twice this can be expanded e.g. 13 ~2.1 times greater than 6 will loop 3 times till the buffer is empty.

Why is this and how can I stop it from looping multiple times if someone enters 6 or more characters.

Side question in this loop malloc gets called everytime to set/clear *string. is this creating a new pointer and I will need to memory clear at the end of each loop, or is it overwritting the existing location for *string?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you *nul-terminate* the string by adding `'\0'` to the end (as the last character)? You can use plain old `0` as well -- the  are the same thing.

Comment: Depending on various terminal settings, your getchar() probably doesn't deliver a character until the user has typed the whole line and hit return.  Once the user hits return, all of the characters are available, and they're returned one at a time by getchar.  So when you type 7 characters followed by return, the loop can do the first six, and then it continues to do the seventh character in a second pass.

Comment: On your second question, calling malloc in the loop allocates a new six-character buffer each time.  You never free that buffer, so your program leaks memory 6 bytes at a time.  (Actually, more than 6, since each malloc probably rounds up to an even binary size, plus there's header information on each allocated block.)

Comment: Since the size of the string is **fixed**, you will be better off declaring string as a `char` *array* instead of `char` *pointer*.

Comment: @zachcbenny You have to use [`free`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) if you use `malloc`.

Comment: The bigger question is why allocate at all. If you expect the user to enter up to 20 or so characters, use a character array of 128-bytes (or more, say `char buf[128];`) to take input from the user using `fgets()` and trim the trailing `'\n'` using `strcspn()` (e.g. `buf[strcspn (buf, "\n")] = 0;`) If you then need permanent storage, allocate for `strlen (buf) + 1` characters and `strcpy (string, buf);`. You must preserve a pointer to the beginning of each allocated block so you can `free()` the memory when done (otherwise you have created a memory leak -- bad).

Comment: You're only consuming at most 6 characters before you print the prompt again.  If you want to read until the next newline, call `getchar` until you see a newline.

Comment: What, exactly, is the desired behavior, and how does it differ from the actual? Read "[How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" for tips.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: since `string` is used as a character array (rather than a C-string), NUL-termination isn't necessary in the sample.

Comment: @outis yep, I snapped to the surreptitious fact that `string` was not a string... `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: "When is a string not a string? When it's a-char." Sort of works.

Comment: `:)`, yep I get it, but `array` or some other name may help someone 5 years from look at that the code and not have to do a double-take. What's in a name? By any other name would a rose not smell as sweet?

Answer (score 1):

The following will achieve what you want:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{    
    while(1)
    {
        char string[6], input;
        printf("\nEnter string: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            input = getchar();
            if(input == '\n')
            {
                break;
            }
            string[i] = input;
        }
        while (input != '\n') input = getchar();//eats away remaining characters
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", string[i]);
            string[i] = 0;//clears the array for next iteration
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While there is no requirement that you include a nul-terminating character at the end of an array, just understand, if you don't, the array cannot be treated as a string -- which makes your choice of variable name `string` misleading.

We will take for true for the moment that you really do want to read `0 - 6` characters only and that you do NOT want to make `string` a string by including the *nul-terminating* character as at the end of input. Given that there are only SIX characters involved, there is no need to dynamically allocate, in fact declaring the pointer to do so, takes more memory than a six-byte array (leaving the compilers potential minimum array size out for now)

If you do need to allocate and copy, you can add that trivially, but for now, lets look at modifying your loop to only read up to six characters no matter how many the user enters. The simple solution is read until `'\n'` or `EOF` but only store up to six characters, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 6          /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {
    
    while (1) {
        char string[MAXC] = "";             /* buffer to hold 6 chars (NOT a string) */
        int n = 0, c = 0;                   /* counter and temp character */
        
        fputs ("enter string: ", stdout);               /* prompt */
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {   /* read char, test \n & EOF */
            if (n < MAXC)                               /* array not full */
                string[n++] = c;                        /* store char, advance counter */
        }
        if (!n)                                         /* \n alone, break */
            break;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                     /* output result */
            printf (i ? " %d" : "%d", string[i]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Now no matter how many characters are input, only up to a max of six will be stored and the rest will be read and silently discarded, emptying `stdin`, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/read_chars
enter string: 12345
49 50 51 52 53
enter string: 123456
49 50 51 52 53 54
enter string: 1234567
49 50 51 52 53 54
enter string: 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
49 50 51 52 53 54
enter string:
```

Let me know if this is what you were after, and also if you need help with the allocation and validation. If you have any further questions, just drop a comment below.